# Load a CSV onto Apache Beam where there is a comma in some of the fields

Tags: csv, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am loading a CSV into Apache Beam, but the CSV I am loading has commas in the fields. It looks like this:

```
ID, Name
1, Barack Obama
2, Barry, Bonds
```

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Hi, anything from anyone here?

Comment: I was planning to use CSV for my transform integration test, since my data contains a lot commas, I switched the output to JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Beam, but a general problem with CSV. It's unclear if the second line should have `ID="2, Barry" Name="Bonds"` or the other way around.

If you can use some context (e.g. ID is always an integer, only one field could possibly contain commas) you could solve this by reading it as a text file line by line and parsing it into separate fields with a custom DoFn (assuming rows also contain newlines).

Generally, non-separating commas should be inside quotes in well-formed CSV, which makes this much more tractable (e.g. it would just work with the [Beam Dataframes](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) read_csv.)

Comment: thanks for the response, i've been scouring for something all day. is it best practice to use beam dataframes? I'm much more familiar with pandas, so working with "dataframes" is a lot more intuitive for me

Comment: I took a look at the data, and indeed non-separating commas were inside double quotes. Also I tried out Beam Dataframes, and although I could make one, I couldn't select columns using use_ncols. I tried emailing them but the email was dead. I guess Beam Dataframes are incomplete.

Comment: `use_ncols` should work, in fact it's in the examples https://beam.apache.org/blog/dataframe-api-preview-available/ Not sure what email you're using, but users@beam.apache.org is active. Beam Dataframes is under active development, but it should be quite usable already.

Comment: i copied the exact code from the example, and received this error: TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_ncols'. this is using version 
Apache Beam 2.26.0 for Python 3 and 

Apache Beam 2.30.0 for Python 3

Comment: The docs are wrong. Pandas read_csv (which Beam leverages) has no `use_ncols` parameter. Instead, I think `usecols` is what you want (and I verified that that works.)